# 'module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot''

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When trying to import pyplot from matplotlib, I get this error (python 3.6). It works fine on my other computer, which has python 3.5, but I don't think it changed much.

I've tried both:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

and

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It's really annoying me that I can't figure this out.

Comment: Can you please post the error.?

Comment: Originally I was just getting what I posted as the title, 'module 'matplotlib' has not attribute 'pyplot''. Then I started messing around, updating anaconda and stuff, and now I'm getting a new message. 'ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' is the last line, after it traces through a lot of files, starting with matplotlib that has pyplot.py in it

Comment: what kind of new message.?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before I posted the new message

Comment: you can check your module.. by first importing and then doing help(matplotlib) and dir(matplotlib). check if it contains pyplot or not. if not, try reinstalling it.

Comment: try this :: >>>import matplotlib

>>>matplotlib.use("Agg")

>>>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: dir(matplotlib) does not contain pyplot as far as i can tell, but pyplot.py still exists in the matplotlib file. uninstalling and reinstalling did not help

Comment: matplotlib.use("Agg") works. What exactly does that do?

Comment: to be honest, i am not aware of what it actually does. but that should solve the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> matplotlib targets many different use cases and output formats. Some people use matplotlib interactively from the python shell and have plotting windows pop up when they type commands. Some people embed matplotlib into graphical user interfaces like wxpython or pygtk to build rich applications. Others use matplotlib in batch scripts to generate postscript images from some numerical simulations, and still others in web application servers to dynamically serve up graphs.
>
> To support all of these use cases, matplotlib can target different outputs, and each of these capabilities is called a backend; the “frontend” is the user facing code, i.e., the plotting code, whereas the “backend” does all the hard work behind-the-scenes to make the figure. There are two types of backends: user interface backends (for use in pygtk, wxpython, tkinter, qt4, or macosx; also referred to as “interactive backends”) and hardcopy backends to make image files (PNG, SVG, PDF, PS; also referred to as “non-interactive backends”).

In yout case you have to choose backend "Agg" to use pyplot.

Solution:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

reference:

- https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend
- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9954

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess:

1:Maybe you have not properly installed matplotlib, you can try this:

```
pip3.6 install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Or just deleted the package and reinstall

2:Check whether you have use the same config environment and execution environment:

In some cases, you have installed packages for your local python interpreter, but you actually run your program on python virtual env. Maybe you have not properly installed the package on virtual env.

Comment: Matplotlib is up to date, I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it, and I'm trying to execute from the command line with no virtual environment. I think its an anaconda issue, but updating that didn't help